# php session is being unset on one page only

Tags: php, session

I have pages which **all include the same file** which begins with `session_start();`. I have four session variables set, and I can navigate through all pages and they remain set successfully:

`print_r($_SESSION): Array ( [first_name] => Daniel [last_name] => Jameson [email] => email@gmail.com [logged_in] => 1 )`

However, when I go to `index.php` all variables are unset! There is no error or warning shown:

`` `print_r($_SESSION): Array ( ) ``

I've tried a million things and I have narrowed it down a bit:

- It is not being unset by the logout script
- There's no whitespace before `session_start();`

There was a mention of UTF-8 with BOM encoded pages, which I **do** have. But I can't seem to find much more info on it.

I can't show you the page itself but I can say that the only php on index.php is included, and is also included on the other pages. There's no difference!

**EDIT**

More testing has suggested that there is some kind of caching going on. Even when I delete the $_SESSION variables from the php files, the SESSION array is still being populated:

`print_r($_SESSION): Array ( [first_name] => Daniel [last_name] => Jameson [email] => email@gmail.com [logged_in] => 1 )`

**EDIT 2**

It has something to do with the index.php filename itself. If I rename the file to index2.php then it works as expected.

Comment: why you can't show us?

Comment: Are you using session_write_close() too? If not, I would try that first...

Comment: did you do session_start() in the logout page ? Please paste in the logout page's code

Comment: Did you check the error log?

Comment: Can you confirm that index.php is actually on the same domain as your other files?

Comment: Thanks all. session_write_close() doesn't fix the problem, session_start() is everywhere (also the logout page isn't the problem), there's nothing in the error logs, and all files are on the same domain. Ahhh